# Retrieving from Database VBA

Tags: database, vba, excel, adodb

I am trying to retrieve from mySQL database.

```
    Dim oRS as ADODB.Recordset
    Dim databaseRecords as Range
    Set oRS = New ADODB.Recordset
    oRS.ActiveConnection = oConn
    oRS.Source = "Select AccID from database123"
    oRS.Open
    databaseRecords.CopyFromRecordset (oRS)
    oRS.Close
    If Not oRS Is Nothing Then Set oRS = Nothing
```

I have already connected to mySQLdatabase. The connection part is fine. I get an error "Object variable or With variable not set" in databaseRecords.CopyFromRecordset (oRS). The database does not have any empty rows.

Comment: You haven't assigned anything to databaseRecords.  It needs to hold a reference to a Range before you can use `.CopyFromRecordSet`. And you don't need the parens around oRS.

Comment: Is this code copied and pasted from the VBA editor, or did you retype it? Retyping code can hide errors, please copy and paste instead. Also, you are missing the code that sets `oConn`, if we can't see it we can't figure out what's wrong (although Tim is probably right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared databaseRecords but not assigned it. It needs to be assigned to an existing (and valid sized) range within the target spreadsheet.